# CodeIgniter fails Join Operation

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I need to use a join operation. This is my code:

```
$this->db->from('d');
        $this->db->where('id',$v);
        $this->db->join('p', 'p.id = d.id');
$deal=$this->db->get();
```

The exception is:

```
Server returned HTTP response code: 500
```

The table is:

```
p(id,home) and d(id, p.id(this value is from p table),school);
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your query

```
    $this->db->from('d');
    $this->db->where('id',$v);
    $this->db->join('p', 'p.id = d.id'); 
    $deal=$this->db->get();
```

where caluse is ambigeous, you have to put it like this

```
  $this->db->where('d.id',$v);
```

also try

```
  $this->db->join('p', 'p.id = d.id', 'inner' or 'left');
```

don't put both just put either inner or left in the join query,hopefully this will solve your problem and also make sure p, d are not synonyms they are actuall  name of tables which exists in DB with same p, d names and have valid columns.

Answer (score 0):

You have to try and check a few things in here:

1) Whether your `database.php` file contains the proper credentials. Look for any silly syntax errors as well.

2) Whether you are loading the `database` class?

3) Some times if you have installed the php package, the mysql driver would not have got installed. check whether you have installed mysql dirver `php5-mysqlnd`?